# VB .net - Linenumber Issue

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a bit of code that pulls through rows from a database connection and should return a linenumber for each row. I'm doing this in the following way.

```
linenum = 0
Do While (rsData.Read())
linenum = linenum + 1
```

Now when I ouput a DB connection with 8 rows, the linenumbers for each of the rows return as 1222222.

I need to determine the correct numbers so I can do the following to change row styles.

```
If ((linenum / 2) = Int(linenum / 2)) Then
html += Chr(13) & "<tr class=""openrow2"">"
Else
html += Chr(13) & "<tr class=""openrow1"">"
End If
```

Any ideas why my rows past the first one seem to only get referred to as linenumber 2 rather than the next number in the series?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we'd need more of the code relating to your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shoot in the dark, but where is your loop statement ?
Also if linenum is an integer why don't use the MOD operator ?

```
linenum = 0 
Do While rsData.Read()
    linenum = linenum + 1 
    If (linenum Mod 2) = 0) Then 
       html += Chr(13) & "<tr class=""openrow2"">" 
    Else 
      html += Chr(13) & "<tr class=""openrow1"">" 
    End If 
    ....
Loop
```

Comment: The loop comes in at the end of the numerous things I do to put details into rows.

I can post the details but will need to strip some stuff out but the loop is definitely there.

Comment: Something inside the loop change the value of linenum?

Comment: Thanks Steve - found a bit of rubbish code that had a linenum alteration in it.

Didn't think to check out anywhere where Linenum was being set. Guess I need a coffee.....

Comment: Welcome to the club @PipBoy. This is why I have a coffee machine right here behind my desk :)